# Facebook expired permissions related issue

Tags: ios, facebook

In my iOS app I am working on support for Facebook's new feature related to permissions being expired in a 90 days period. What i am trying to do is set a test account with expired permissions in App Dashboard.

In my App Dashboard what i tried doing exactly is:
1) go to "Change permissions this test user granted to app" and then delete "user_friends";
2) go to "Change data access expiration time" and set a small amount of time.

Unfortunately, no matter what i do, when i obtain a FBSDKAccessToken object, the _permissions container still contains "user_friends".
As a result, i can't identify the state when i need to call for permissions reauthorization.

Could anyone be so kind to explain, what am i doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Deleted and expired are two different things. If you want to test automatic expiration, then don’t remove the permission yourself. _“when i obtain a FBSDKAccessToken object, the _permissions container still contains "user_friends".”_ - could be a cached result?

Comment: In my application i rely fully on the SDK  and always use it to obtain relevant object. So unless SDK does cache the object (which i don't think is the case), i wouldn't count on that.

As for permission expiration vs removal. As i described, i tried setting a small (1 min) threshold for permissions to expire. But unfortunately FBSDKAccessToken still store something like:

_dataAccessExpirationDate = 2019-05-01
_expirationDate = 2019-04-01

Comment: Log out or invalidate the token, and then login again … what does it say then?